# Can I temporarily store evolution points in myself with the Summoner's Aspect ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, summoner, eidolon

When a Summoner uses the [Aspect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Aspect-Su-) ability to divert evolution points to take on evolutions for himself, can those points then later be diverted back to his Eidolon's pool or are they permanently stuck in his pool? I wish to use Aspect as a way to store points and not have to remove evolutions from my eidolon in order to get a 3 or 4 point evolution.

Comment: You get to change your evolutions when you level why do you need to "store points"?

Comment: @Nickmagus maybe there's no good evolutions for the eidolon right now, but the summoner could benefit for a level or two, until the eidolon can get something good.

Comment: For roleplay purposes, I want to keep the Eidolon's form evolving in a pretty linear fashion. I've already decided getting rid of Climb in order to have an extra point for Flight would make sense. However, there is one spot where I want to give my character some lesser one or two cost evolutions that then are transferred into powerful four cost evolutions that are practically bigger versions of the lesser ones. I understand "storing points" makes no sense as far as mechanics go, but for roleplay purposes I think it would suit my purposes better. Perhaps something to just work with my DM about?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could store the points and give your PC the 1-2 point evolution, and then change them out when you gain a level, just as you can change the delegation of the other evolution pool points.

> #### Aspect
>
> At 10th level, a summoner can **divert up to 2 points** from his eidolon’s evolution pool to add evolutions to himself. ... **The summoner can change the evolutions he receives from these points any time he can change the eidolon’s evolutions.**

> #### Evolution Pool
>
> <sup>*(from Eidolon abilities)*</sup>
>
> ... Whenever the summoner gains a level, the number in this pool increases and the summoner can spend these points to change the abilities of the eidolon. **These choices are not set. The summoner can change them whenever he gains a level.**

> #### Transmogrify
>
> Your eidolon's form shifts and transforms. This spell allows you to change any of the eidolon's evolutions by allocating its evolution pool on new evolutions. **If you have the aspect or greater aspect ability, this spell also allows you to change the evolution points spent to modify you, including removing or adding points as allowed by those abilities.**

The way I've read those is that every time the summoner gains a level in Summoner, he/she effectively resets the evolutions, gains the full pool of evolution points, then spends them as desired. With the *Aspect* ability, you are diverting points from that pool at any point you could change the eidolon's evolutions.

Thus, when you gain a level and want to store points, you divert the two from the evolution pool. The next time you gain a level, you choose whether you'd like to divert 0, 1, or 2 points with that ability again.

Also with how *Transmogrify* spell functions, moving points back and forth between *Aspect* and the *Evolution Pool* when you level up seems to be completely viable.